# How to sync with 2 main items in Laravel syncWithoutDetaching

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

The Cart_product table has 4 columns:

```
id | cart_id | product_id | size_id | quantity
```

with relationship of `belongsToMany` for `Cart`, `Product` and `Size`.

User can add a product with deferent sizes but not same size, so product->id = 1 can have size->id = 1 and size->id = 2.

I want to **sync** product->id and size->id where only have 1 row of same product->id and size->id.

with this code, only my product->id is synced.

```
        $this->cart->products()->syncWithoutDetaching(
[$product->id => ['size_id' => $size->id, 'quantity' => $quantity]]
            );
```

As I said I need to sync product->id and size->id, I can have a product with deferent sizes:

```
id | cart_id | product_id | size_id | quantity
1  | 1       |1           | 2       |2
2  | 1       |1           | 3       |1
```

but not a product with same sizes:

```
id | cart_id | product_id | size_id | quantity
1  | 1       |1           | 2       |2
2  | 1       |1           | 2       |1
```

I have checked many cases as :

```
        $this->cart->products()->syncWithoutDetaching(
[$product->id, $size->id => ['quantity' => $quantity]]
            );
```

But it can't take true result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BelongsToMany relation are made for pivot tables with only two foreign keys as their unicity index. In your case, the unicity is obtained with three indexes `cart_id`, `product_id` and `size_id` so you can't use any predefined method from the relation to achieve your goal.

*side note: I suggest you add this constraint in your database so it triggers an error if your code tries to insert two rows with the same values in those indexes*

To sync with three indexes I suggest you use `updateOrInsert()` or `upsert()`

```
\DB::table('your_pivot_table_name')->updateOrInsert(
    ['cart_id' => 1, 'product_id' => 1, 'size_id' => 2], //the unique index to look out for
    ['quantity' => 2] //the other fields to sync
);
```

Another idea would be to declare the pivot table as [Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) and add the method to "sync" using `updateOrCreate()` to it.

**EDIT**: upsert

```
DB::table('cart_product')->upsert(
    [
        [ 'cart_id' => $this->instance()->id, 'product_id' => $product->id, 'size_id' => $size->id, 'quantity' => (int) $qunatity]
    ], 
    ['cart_id', 'product_id', 'size_id'], 
    ['quantity']
);
```

Comment: thank you for the clean comment, but I get this error with both upsert and ... also I change the cart_id and so on type to unsignedBigInteger but same error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `cart_product` (`cart_id`, `product_id`, `size_id`) values (1, 2, 2) on duplicate key update `cart_id` = values(`cart_id`), `product_id` = values(`product_id`), `size_id` = values(`size_id`))

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi use the example i provided using `updateOrCreate` or can you comment how you called `upsert()` in answer to this comment, because upsert has a third parameter on what fields should be updated (apart of the 3 indexes) and you need to provide `['quantity']` in it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: public function add(Product $product, Size $size, $qunatity = 1){DB::table('cart_product')->updateOrCreate(['cart_id' => $this->instance()->id, 'product_id' => $product->id, 'size_id' => $size->id], ['quantity' => (int) $qunatity]);}:BadMethodCallException Call to ... method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()
 public function add(Product $product, Size $size, $qunatity = 1{DB::table('cart_product')->upsert( [[ 'cart_id' => $this->instance()->id, 'product_id' => $product->id,size_id' => $size->id,]], ['quantity' => (int) $qunatity]);}:'quantity' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi For the `updateOrCreate` was implemented in laravel 5.3, if you have an older version, it is not available. For the upsert, the third parameter has only the indexes. try this `DB::table('cart_product')->upsert( [[ 'cart_id' => $this->instance()->id, 'product_id' => $product->id,size_id' => $size->id, 'quantity' => (int) $qunatity]], ['cart_id', 'product_id', 'size_id'], ['quantity']);` added it to the answer

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi there was a typo for `updateOrCreate()`, it is available only threw a model class like `Product::updateOrCreate()`, but when you use `\DB::` directly you need to use `updateOrInsert()` so try `DB::table('cart_product')->updateOrInsert(['cart_id' => $this->instance()->id, 'product_id' => $product->id, 'size_id' => $size->id], ['quantity' => (int) $qunatity]);` also edited the answer, sorry for the confusion.*